# how to filter only specifc information while using "within" in R

Tags: r

I am trying to filter only the NA after running the below code. But i could not formulate a code for the same. The below code is inside a function where the Raw_data is finally divided into different data frame basis on the company.

```
Raw_data<-within(Raw_data,{
      Neg_outliers=NA
      Pos_outliers=NA
      Neg_outliers[Company == "2002"]<-ifelse(Paid_age<mean_two_sd_negative,"negative_outlier","NA")
      Neg_outliers[Company == "2203"]<-ifelse(Paid_age<mean_two_sd_negative,"negative_outlier","NA")
      Neg_outliers[Company == "1804"]<-ifelse(Paid_age<mean_two_sd_negative,"negative_outlier","NA")
      Neg_outliers[Company == "2401A"]<-ifelse(Paid_age<mean_two_sd_negative,"negative_outlier","NA")
      Neg_outliers[Company == "2401B"]<-ifelse(Paid_age<mean_two_sd_negative,"negative_outlier","NA")
      Pos_outliers[Company == "2002"]<-ifelse(Paid_age>mean_two_sd_positive,"positive_outlier","NA")
      Pos_outliers[Company == "2203"]<-ifelse(Paid_age>mean_two_sd_positive,"positive_outlier","NA")
      Pos_outliers[Company == "1804"]<-ifelse(Paid_age>mean_two_sd_positive,"positive_outlier","NA")
      Pos_outliers[Company == "2401A"]<-ifelse(Paid_age>mean_two_sd_positive,"positive_outlier","NA")
      Pos_outliers[Company == "2401B"]<-ifelse(Paid_age>mean_two_sd_positive,"positive_outlier","NA")

    })
```

Comment: Remove quotes from `NA`, since it's a logical value. Then, what you're probably looking for is `Pos_outliers[is.na(Company)]` (within the `within`)).

Answer (score 0):

The `ifelse` statements aren't needed here, since your new columns already have `NA` in them. In any case, as @jay.sf points out, you were writing the character string `"NA"` instead of `NA` to the new columns, which probably isn't what you wanted.

Instead of having a character string or an `NA` indicating whether a value is an outlier, why not just have a logical column of `TRUE` and `FALSE`? This will make it much easier to filter out your data later.

Your whole code can be replaced with this, which is much easier to read, understand and maintain:

```
companies <- c("2202", "2203", "1804", "2401A", "2401B")
matching  <- Raw_data$Company %in% companies

Raw_data  <- within(Raw_data, {
      Pos_outliers <- matching & Paid_age > mean_two_sd_positive
      Neg_outliers <- matching & Paid_age < mean_two_sd_positive
})
```

So if you want to add a new company, you just add a single value to `companies` instead of a whole line of code, and if you want to change the variables you are testing you only need to change one or two variable names instead of ten.